# Couchbase Admin Console Settings Notification

Tags: couchbase

On my local instance of Couchbase (4.1.0) a notification icon has appeared on the settings tab inside of Admin Console. When clicking on the Settings tab and navigating to the sub tabs there doesn't appear to be any new information and the icon remains. **What is the icon notification used to indicate**/ additionally **how do I get rid of the notification**

[image: Notification icon top right of fhe scree,]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a notification to upgrade couchbase to 4.5. Not sure why it never appeared before since 4.5 has been out for a while